# Show and Hide contents base on radio button selection in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to display different contents base on radio button select in jquery.

My HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="1" <?=(isset($type) && $type == 'Person') ?  ' checked' : ''?>> Person
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="2" <?=(isset($type) && $type == 'Institute') ?  ' checked' : ''?>> Institute
  </label>
</div>
```

This is how I tried in jquery to display two different contents for each radio button selection.

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="b_type"]').on('change',function(){
  var sel = $(this);
  if(sel.val() == 1){
    $('#person-block').show();
    $('#person-institute').show();
  }else{
    $('#institute-block').show();
    $('#person-block').hide();
});
```

This code is working in some way. But there is a problem. Default radio button `checked` is dynamic. Lets assume second button is checked when the page is loading, then it display `#persion-block` contents. But I want to display `#institute-block` contents.

If I click on first button and then click on second its working.

Can anybody tell me how to figure this out? 
Thank you.

Comment: Just click the element inside the document.ready `$('input[type="radio"][name="b_type"]:checked').click();`

Comment: @JYoThI Can you show me an example?

Comment: check my below answer

Comment: @JYoThI, Yes its working perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it that helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger the change event in the element inside the document.ready

Note : You have some id typo .

```js
$('input[type="radio"][name="b_type"]').on('change',function(){
alert($(this).val());
  if($(this).val() == "1"){
    $('#person-block').show();
    $('#institute-block').hide();
  }else{
    $('#institute-block').show();
    $('#person-block').hide();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="radio"][name="b_type"]:checked').change();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="1" > Person
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="2" checked> Institute
  </label>
</div>
<div id="person-block" >
  Person
</div>
<div id="institute-block" >
  Institute
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check which button is checked on page load with the `:checked` pseudo class (additionally to your existing event handler):

```js
if ($('input[type="radio"][name="b_type"]:checked').val() == 1) {
  $('#person-block').show();
} else {
  $('#institute-block').show();
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="1" > Person
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="2" checked> Institute
  </label>
</div>
<div id="person-block" class="block">
  Person
</div>
<div id="institute-block" class="block">
  Institute
</div>
```

Additionally I would recommend hiding both elements on default to avoid showing the content of both before the JS has been loaded.

Comment: This is working but one issue. Content toggling is now working when each button select

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[type="radio"][name="b_type"]').on('change', function () {

                var sel = $(this).filter(':checked').val();
               
                if (sel == 1) {
                    $('#person-block').show();
                    $('#institute-block').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#institute-block').show();
                    $('#person-block').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="1" > Person
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="2" checked> Institute
  </label>
</div>
 <div style="display:none" id="person-block"  class="block">
      Person
    </div>
    <div style="display:none" id="institute-block" class="block">
      Institute
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use .is(':checked')

```
if($('#myradiobutton').is(':checked')){
 // this
}else{
 // that
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked but problem is same.

Comment: You have to execute the function on load too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[type="radio"][name="b_type"]').on('change', function () {

                var sel = $(this).filter(':checked').val();
               
                if (sel == 1) {
                    $('#person-block').show();
                    $('#institute-block').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#institute-block').show();
                    $('#person-block').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="1" <?=(isset($type) && $type == 'Person') ?  ' checked' : ''?> Person
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="b_type" value="2" <?=(isset($type) && $type == 'Institute') ?  ' checked' : ''?>Institute
  </label>
</div>
 <div style="display:none" id="person-block"  class="block">
      Person
    </div>
    <div style="display:none" id="institute-block" class="block">
      Institute
    </div>
```

Comment: Just check but problem is same

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#redio1").click(function(){
    $('#person-block').css('display','block');
    $('#person-institute').css('display','block');
})
$("#redio2").click(function(){
    $('#institute-block').css('display','block');
    $('#person-block').css('display','none');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="redio1" name="b_type" value="1" <?=(isset($type) && $type == 'Person') ?  ' checked' : ''?>> Person
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="redio2" name="b_type" value="2" <?=(isset($type) && $type == 'Institute') ?  ' checked' : ''?>> Institute
  </label>
</div>
<div id="person-block" style="color:red;display:none;">person-block</div>
<div id="person-institute" style="color:black;display:none;">person-institute</div>
```